# reactjs: call a function after setState used with prevState

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to call a function after my state is changed.

The following is the code. Its not working

```
    this.setState(prevState => (
            {
                test: "sample"
            },() => {
                    console.log("after statechanges")
            }
        ));
```

whereas the below works, but i want to use the prevstate.

```
this.setState(
        {
            test: "sample"
        },() => {
                console.log("after statechanges")
        }
    );
```

Comment: Hi! I'm not sure, but there is not such a syntax at all. After state changes all the lifecycle events will be triggered, why would you need a callback. Also state changes can be merges and so on

Answer (score 3):

You forgot closing parentheses here `({ test: "sample" })`

```
this.setState(
    (prevState) => ({ test: "sample" }),
    () => { console.log("after statechanges"); }
);
```